# Multi-Paxos Full Disclosure: How does the acceptor know about the chosen value after it marks an entry as chosen?

Tags: consensus

[image]

I am learning multi paxos from the slides of [this](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/~ongaro/userstudy/paxos.pdf) made by John Ousterhout and Diego Ongaro.

In this section talking about Full Disclosure, it says the acceptor mark entry 6 as chosen, since the proposer tells it, with the same proposal 3.4 and firstUnchosenIndex 7.

My Question is: As you can see, proposal 3.4 is for entry 8 now, how can the acceptor simply mark entry 6 as chosen without knowing the chosen value?

Answer (score 0):

i think because when proposer become leader.it send accept RPCs in it's term with firstUnchosenIndex ,so if the accepter found it's index<firstUnchosenIndex and acceptedProposal[index]'s proposalNum == leader's proposalNum. it knows that this leader has chosen index's value,because there is acceptedProposal[index],so log[index] shoud has value which comes from proposer who has the proposalNum. so it konws index is the chosen one which in picture is 6.